# Multiple variables for the same command

Tags: cmd.exe

I'm new to cmd and was wondering if there's an easier way of retpying a variable in a command. For example, I have to do two commands for a set of 96 files and each time I would hit the up arrrow key, get my old commands back and change a variable from 1 to 2, then 2 to 3 and so forth.

i.e.:

Desktop\InitialProcess_230 Process230input.fasta -output Process230.fasta

Then each time I want to do the next file which would be InitialProcess_231 and so on, I would change that in the command by scrolling along and removing 0 and putting a 1. Doing that for almost a 100 files seems like a hassle.

Comment: Have you considered writing a batch file instead of running the commands one by one?

Answer (score 0):

Save a batch file with the code below. It will run your command starting at 230 and run up to 330.

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set var=229
for /L %%A in (1,1,100) do (
    set /a num=%%A+!var!
    Desktop\InitialProcess_!num! Process!num!input.fasta -output Process!num!.fasta
)
echo Done
pause
```

The for loop has the parameters (1,1,100) which means it will start at 1, step by 1, and increment to 100. This number %%A gets added to !var! which we set as 229 (resulting in !num! = 230, 231...). If you want to change the starting number, change the line:

```
set var=229
```

If your command isn't working right, put an echo before the actual command, like this:

```
    echo Desktop\InitialProcess_!num! Process!num!input.fasta -output Process!num!.fasta
```

This wont run the command, but print out exactly what it looks like. This helps with troubleshooting. Hopefully this helps, best of luck!

Comment: I image you'll have to change your path in the command, so be aware of that.